# Using mutate in custom function with mutation condition as argument

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Is it possible to construct a function, say `my_mut(df, condition)` such that `df` is a dataframe, `condition` is a string describing a mutation, and somewhere in the function,   the mutation of `df` according to `condition` is used?

For example, if `df` has a `foo` column and you run `my_mut(df, "foo = 2*foo")`, then somewhere within `my_mut()` there would be a row that produces the same dataframe as `df %>% mutate(foo = 2*foo)`.

I managed to do something similar with `filter` using `eval` and `parse`.

```
update_filt <- function(df,
                        filt,
                        col){

  sub <- df %>%
    filter(eval(parse(text = filt))) %>%
    mutate("{{col}}" := 2*{{ col }})

  remain <- df %>%
    filter(eval(parse(
                text = paste0("!(",filt,")")
                ))
           )

  return(rbind(sub, remain))
}
```

I am not sure the `update_filt` function is faultproof, but it works in some cases at least, e.g., `library(gapminder) date_filt(gapminder, "year == 1952", pop)` returns the expected outcome.

The same trick does not seem to work with `mutate` though. For example,

```
update_mut <- function(df, mutation){
  # Evaluate mutation expression
  df %>% mutate(eval(parse(text = mutation))
}
```

produces outcomes like

```
library(gapminder)
update_mut(gapminder, "year = 2*year")
# A tibble: 1,704 × 7
   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap `eval(parse(text = mutation))`
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>                          <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.                           3904
 2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.                           3914
 3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.                           3924
 4 Afghanistan Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.                           3934
 5 Afghanistan Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.                           3944
 6 Afghanistan Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.                           3954
 7 Afghanistan Asia       1982    39.9 12881816      978.                           3964
 8 Afghanistan Asia       1987    40.8 13867957      852.                           3974
 9 Afghanistan Asia       1992    41.7 16317921      649.                           3984
10 Afghanistan Asia       1997    41.8 22227415      635.                           3994
# … with 1,694 more rows
```

Instead of the expected

```
gapminder %>% mutate(year = 2*year)

# A tibble: 1,704 × 6
   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fct>       <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       3904    28.8  8425333      779.
 2 Afghanistan Asia       3914    30.3  9240934      821.
 3 Afghanistan Asia       3924    32.0 10267083      853.
 4 Afghanistan Asia       3934    34.0 11537966      836.
 5 Afghanistan Asia       3944    36.1 13079460      740.
 6 Afghanistan Asia       3954    38.4 14880372      786.
 7 Afghanistan Asia       3964    39.9 12881816      978.
 8 Afghanistan Asia       3974    40.8 13867957      852.
 9 Afghanistan Asia       3984    41.7 16317921      649.
10 Afghanistan Asia       3994    41.8 22227415      635.
# … with 1,694 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your formula is always like **origianl** = **do_something_original()**, this may helps.(for `dplyr` version >= 1.0)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

update_mut <- function(df, mutation){
  xx <- word(mutation, 1)
  df %>% 
    mutate("{xx}" := eval(parse(text = mutation)))
}
update_mut(gapminder, "year = 2*year")

   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fct>       <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       3904    28.8  8425333      779.
 2 Afghanistan Asia       3914    30.3  9240934      821.
 3 Afghanistan Asia       3924    32.0 10267083      853.
 4 Afghanistan Asia       3934    34.0 11537966      836.
 5 Afghanistan Asia       3944    36.1 13079460      740.
 6 Afghanistan Asia       3954    38.4 14880372      786.
 7 Afghanistan Asia       3964    39.9 12881816      978.
 8 Afghanistan Asia       3974    40.8 13867957      852.
 9 Afghanistan Asia       3984    41.7 16317921      649.
10 Afghanistan Asia       3994    41.8 22227415      635.
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
my_mut <- function(df, df_filter, ...){
  df %>% 
    filter({{ df_filter }}) %>% 
    mutate(newvar = 'other function stuff',
           ...)
}

example_df <- data.frame(a = c('zebra', 'some value'),
                         b = 1:2)

example_df %>% 
  my_mut(df_filter = a == 'some value', 
         b = b*5)
#>            a  b               newvar
#> 1 some value 10 other function stuff
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you can't use `...` because you're already using it in the function for something else, you could wrap the `mutation` argument in `tibble` when calling the function.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
my_mut <- function(df, df_filter, mutation){
  df %>% 
    filter({{ df_filter }}) %>% 
    mutate(newvar = 'other function stuff',
           {{ mutation }})
}

example_df <- data.frame(a = c('zebra', 'some value'),
                         b = 1:2)

example_df %>% 
  my_mut(df_filter = a == 'some value', 
         mutation = tibble(b = b*5))
#>            a  b               newvar
#> 1 some value 10 other function stuff
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that mutate doesn't understand the assignment, because all the syntax is evaluated inside `eval`. So mutate simply thinks this is a nameless expression and assigns as its name the whole text of the expression.

One way to circumvent this would be to `eval` the whole thing, including the `mutate` verb, as below.

```
update_mut <- function(df, mutation) {
  # Evaluate the mutation expression
  eval(parse(text = paste0("mutate(df, ", mutation, ")")))
}
```

Another way would be, inside the update_mut function, to split the `mutation` parameter by the `=` character, therefore obtaining the name of the variable and the expressions. Therefore you could use a dynamic variable assingment in mutate. However this would only be more to do, since the above code simply solves the problem.